# How to reverse a sublist in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given the following list:

```
a = ['aux iyr','bac oxr','lmn xpn']

c = []
for i in a:
    x = i.split(" ")
    b= x[1][::-1] --- Got stuck after this line
```

Can anyone help me how to join it to the actual list and bring the expected output

output = ['aux ryi','bac rxo','lmn npx']

Comment: Could there be more than two tokens per string and if so, what would happen after the second?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need two lines of codes, first splitting the values:

```
b = [x.split() for x in a]
```

Which returns:

```
[['aux', 'iyr'], ['bac', 'oxr'], ['lmn', 'xpn']]
```

And then reverting the order:

```
output = [x[0] +' '+ x[1][::-1] for x in b]
```

Which returns:

```
['aux ryi', 'bac rxo', 'lmn npx']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following simple comprehension:

```
[" ".join((x, y[::-1])) for x, y in map(str.split, a)]
# ['aux ryi', 'bac rxo', 'lmn npx']
```